# WiX: How to detect URL Rewrite is installed on IIS

Tags: iis, wix, windows-installer

I am using WiX 3.10 to create an MSI for installing an IIS (7.5 or higher) website. The website requires the URL Rewrite extension in IIS.

Is there a way of detecting whether the URL Rewrite extension is installed in IIS in the launch conditions of the WiX project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform a Registry search to this key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\URL Rewrite

or a file shearch to this file:

> %SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll